# Out of bound error when trying to combine plots using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to create an combined plot by first creating sub-plots grouped by sub-categories and then combining them into a single plot grouped by a parent category.

A MWE is below. Here, I'm trying to plot `mpg` for `weight` by first grouping by `carb` and `am`, and then aggregating all the child plots under each parent `am` value into a single plot by grouping by `am` alone. The desired final output is a single plot for each value of `am` composed of sub-plots for individual values of `carb`.

However, I keep running into an index bounds error.

Here `patchwork::wrap_plots` accepts "multiple ggplots or a list containing ggplot objects".

```
mtDT <- setDT(copy(mtcars))

mtDT[, .(plot = list(ggplot(data = .SD) + geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)))), by=.(carb,am)][,
.(list(patchwork::wrap_plots(plot))), by=am]

> Error: Index out of bounds
```

I also tried the following approach, but that threw a type error about inputs to `wrap_plots` not being ggplots.

```
mtDT[, .(plot = list(ggplot(data = .SD) + geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)))), by=.(carb,am)][,
  .(plotlist = list(plot)), by=am][,
   comboplot:=patchwork::wrap_plots(plotlist)]

>Error: Only know how to add ggplots and/or grobs
```

I'm aware of `facets` in `ggplot`, but I do it this way for finer control of plots.

Comment: Good question, I'm stumped but am thinking about it. FYI, `setDT(copy(.))` is not necessary here, `as.data.table` does everything you need (and it often preferred over `setDT`). Even if the argument is already a `data.table`, it performs a copy under the hood; if it is not already a DT, it becomes one.

Comment: @r2evans I'd say it is a bug in data.table, see my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't fully understand why this happens but this appears to be a bug in data.table. It results from using `lapply` where I would use a `for` loop (because no return value is needed). I suggest you report this to the data.table issue tracker.

This is the offending [call within `[.data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/data.table.R#L1892C1-L1900C15):

```
tmp <- mtDT[, .(plot = list(ggplot(data = .SD) + geom_point(aes(x=wt, y=mpg)))), 
     by=.(carb,am)]
a <- tmp[,.(list(patchwork::wrap_plots(plot)))][[1]]

MAX_DEPTH = 5L
runlock = function(x, current_depth = 1L) {
  if (is.list(x) && current_depth <= MAX_DEPTH) {  # is.list() used to be is.recursive(), #4814
    if (inherits(x, 'data.table')) .Call(data.table:::C_unlock, x)
    else return(lapply(x, runlock, current_depth = current_depth + 1L))
  }
  return(invisible())
}

runlock(a)
#Error in `X[[i]]`:
#! Index out of bounds
#Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If I replace the `lapply` loop with a `for` loop, it appears to work:

```
runlock = function(x, current_depth = 1L) {
  if (is.list(x) && current_depth <= MAX_DEPTH) {  # is.list() used to be is.recursive(), #4814
    if (inherits(x, 'data.table')) .Call(data.table:::C_unlock, x)
    else return(for(y in x) runlock(y, current_depth = current_depth + 1L))
  }
  return(invisible())
}

runlock(a)
#no error
```

I suspect the issue results from this code in `lapply`:

```
if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
        X <- as.list(X)
```

This turns fun stuff like environments or objects of class "uneval" into lists. And apparently there can be dragons if you then try to iterate over these lists.